# Conditional linking through static library

Tags: c++, linker, g++, static-libraries, clang++

I’m writing a big static library in C++. In that library, I use symbols from plenty of static and dynamic libraries. When I “make” it, I don’t need to link against any libs because it’s static. Here’s my problem: my static library is **very** generic. It provides several implementations for a same interface (you can see the implementations like *drivers*; the libA provides its own implementation and libB its and so on). Those implementations are **not intended to be used together**, because some of them are platform dependent.

Problems appear when linking against my lib. Clients have to link against all the libs my lib used symbols from, even if the client’s code doesn’t depend on any symbol of a lib. For instance, if the client’s code only depends on *libA*, he still has to link against *libB* because my static library has some symbols from *libB*.

Do you know a way to preclude such a behavior, and only link against the actually used libraries, deducing symbols in the client’s code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely dynamically linking your lib against the other libs. Try to link against the static versions of theses.

Comment: symbols can be from static **or** dynamic libs, I can’t link against static only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your library is trying to use symbols that are expected to be `defined` by client's code. You would like the linker to `not link` certain parts of your library if client's code did not have `certain symbols`.Is that right?

If the above fits your requirement, consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol. I am not sure which tool chain you are using, but if supported weak symbols are a greay way to achieve conditional linking.

Comment: yeah it’s what I want. My static library has a lot of static symbols, but I want them not to be exported in the final program (so we don’t care whether they’re defined)

Comment: do you know if clang++ supports such a feature? I use both g++ and clang++

Comment: @skp not sure about `clang++` but `GNU gcc(and g++)` certainly supports this feature. From a bit of googling I am led to believe that `#pragma weak` is the corresponding feature in `clang++`. I suggest adding the lables g++ and clang++; that would attract some of the experts in the area to comment.

Comment: But, if it is such a library, is it good to force its users to some chosen compilers? I've had few situations, when I needed to use such libraries. One of them needed compiler A, and the second compiler B. And I must say, I was furiously mad at the creators.

Comment: I was under the impression that each combination of the static library and the client application linking with that static library will always use the same tool chain. It is simply that the client applications vary in terms of implementation and only need a subset of the symbols to be linked in. I don't expect the g++ and clang++ to coexist, i.e. library created with one tool chain but linking with an application that was compiled using another. I have no idea if such is permissible between clang++ and g++.

Comment: @Aravind, you missed the point. -- Have a source-code of to two big libraries, which generally should work with my platform. That is, all preliminaries of hardware and system are satisfied. But one have some specific code for gcc, and the other for IBM XL. -- If you say, it is good I can't use them, only because of some features not even connected with their functionality, ... ... I will deeply disagree (eventually start shooting).

Comment: @Number47 before you load your gun, you said some specific code for a specific tool chain. As long as these sections of code are conditionally compiled such that only the intended toolchain sees the relevant code, you effectively have two sets of code one for each toolchain. However once you have built a library (i.e. obtained the object code) using a specific toolchain and attempted to link it with another set of object files compiled with another toolchain, you are pointing the gun to your own foot (unless you know the toolchains are compatible and will stay that way for maintenence sake).

Comment: @Aravind, in this case - as far as I can see - the specific code will force one or more pre-choosed of those tool chains. But what the code does, does not require any of them. Thus forcing any is perfectly wrong. -- Such way of thinking is probably one of the things which brought natively compiled languages down. I'm afraid.

Comment: I am beginning to think either we are talking about the same thing or two completely different things. I am trying to state that your code if using any toolchain driven features (say using `__attribute__`) is not going to be portable. The problem is the usecase where a single library is supposed to auto-size itself based on client code throwing away unused code, automagically. Solution suggested would use a toolchain specific feature to accomplish that, hence would not be portable. A platfrom specific application would be able to benefit from that, since there will only be a single toolchain.